# Solving a simple system of linear equations with a constant

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of the constant, c, does the following system have one solution?

$ 2x-y=10 $

$ -cx+2y=5 $

The answer, apparently, is that there is a solution for any value of c, given by

$ x = 25/(4-c) $ and $ y = 10(1+c)(4-c) $

Now, how might I go about even finding a solution like this algebraically? Or is it something that you're supposed to look at, visualize, and just "know". There is nothing in my textbook except for the answer provided above and I have no idea how to derive this but it seems to work when you plug in the numbers. Is there any formulaic way to derive the solutions to x and y above?

Comment: What if $c=4$? What is the solution?

Comment: Can you write the system as a matrix equation $M\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right] = b$? When can you solve this system?

Comment: Remember that $c$ represents a number. Just go like you would usually solve it if $c$ where written as a number.

Comment: Also, is this homework? If so, we can mark it as so so we know it is homework.

Comment: I understand that c is a constant, but my question is related to the answer. How can I derive a general solution such as that provided by x and y? How would one ever know that the the answer is $ x=25/(4-c) $, for any value of c, for example... How does one derive such a solution merely from the the two equations provided. That's my question, and I think it's a little more involved than simply inputting random numbers as constants and seeing if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this as follows, we have:

$$ 2x-y=10 \\ -cx+2y=5 $$

One solution is to add $2 \times$ the first equation to the second, yielding:

$$-c x + 4 x = 25 \implies x = \dfrac{25}{4-c}$$

Now, we substitute this $x$ value back into the first equation and find $y$ as:

$$y = \dfrac{10(c+1)}{4-c}$$

You could have solved this with Gaussian Elimination, Cramer's Rule ... Using Gaussian Elimination, we have:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & \frac{25}{4-c} \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{10 (c+1)}{4-c} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Compare that to the solution above.

**Note:** The comments are saying that if $c = 4$, we divide by zero, so that is a point we must avoid, else there is no solution. Every other value, except that one, is fair game.

If you are having a difficult time seeing this try  $c = 4$:

$$ ~~2x-y=10 \\ -4x+2y=5 $$

Now, solve this and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, setting $c=4$ implies that $-4x+2y=20$ and $-4x+2y=5$, which must be impossible, since identical equations can't have different solutions. Thanks for the help! I seem to get it now.